# space or &nbsp; not outputting in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following being extracted from an XML and being put into a jQuery variable.

```
 links.append($("<a href='"+alink+"'></a>&nbsp;").html(desc));
```

...however the `&nbsp;` does not output onto the page. I need this to separate the hrefs on output

I have also tried

```
links.append($("<a href='"+alink+"'></a>").html(desc));
    links.append($("&nbsp;"));
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better style with css, something like :

```
links.append($("<a class='link' href='"+alink+"'></a>").html(desc));
```

in css :

```
a.link {
padding-left : 5px ;
padding-right : 5px ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("<a href='"+alink+"'></a>&nbsp;")
```

Yeah, that's actually only creating the `<a>` element, and discarding the nbsp. When you pass a string into the `$()` function that looks like(*) HTML, jQuery creates the stretch of markup between the first `<` in the string and the last `>`. If you've got any leading or trailing content outside those, it gets thrown away(**). You could fool jQuery by saying:

```
$("<a href='"+alink+"'></a>&nbsp;<!-- don't ignore me! -->")
```

This doesn't seem to be documented anywhere, makes no sense whatsoever, and might be considered a bug, but it has been jQuery's normal behaviour for some time so it's probably not going away.

When you pass an HTML string to the `append` function (and other manipulation methods) directly instead of via the `$` function, this behaviour does not occur. So:

```
links.append("<a href='"+alink+"'></a>&nbsp;");
```

actually does keep the space. But a better way forward is to stop throwing HTML strings about, so you don't have to worry about `alink` containing `'`, `<` or `&` characters either, and work in a more DOM style:

```
var link= $('<a/>');
link.attr('href', alink);
link.html(desc);
links.append(link);
links.append('\xA0');
```

Or, more concisely, using jQuery 1.4's `props` argument shortcut:

```
links.append($('<a/>', {href: alink, html: desc}));
links.append('\xA0');
```

assuming that `desc` is really something that should contain HTML markup; if not, use `text` instead.

(I used `\xA0`, the JavaScript string literal way to include a character U+00A0 NON-BREAKING SPACE as it is a whole two characters shorter than the HTML entity reference. Woohoo!)

(*: how does it tell that a string is HTML? Why, by checking to see if there's a `<` and `>` character in it, in that order, of course. Meaning it'll get fooled if you try to use a selector that has those characters in. Brilliant, jQuery, brilliant.(***))

(**: why? see line 125 of jQuery 1.4.2. It builds the HTML fragment from `match[1]`—the group from the first `<` to the last `>` in `quickExpr`—and not the original string or `match[0]`.)

(***: I'm being sarcastic. The insane over-overloading of the `$` function is one of jQuery's worst features.)

Answer (score 0):

you could try

```
 &#160;
```